# Dialog closes immediately

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog

I have a page that auto opens a dialog box. before, you have to click in it to close, but now it automatically closes immediately without even seeing whats inside the dialog box. here's my code:

```
if (jQuery('#renewalNotice').length)
    {   
        jQuery('#renewalNotice').dialog({ width: 518, title: 'Important Notice', autoOpen: true, draggable: false, modal: true, resizable: false, stack: false });
    }

<div id="renewalNotice" style="display: none;">
    <div id="subscription-notice">
        <span class="daysLeft"<?=($daysRemaining <= 5 ? ' style="color: #aa0000;"' : '')?>><?=$daysRemaining?></span>

        <span class="ksDetails">
        Call us: +61 3 3333 3333<br />
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The jQueryUI website has a working code sample here: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/.  It looks to me like your `.dialog` call might be going out of scope the way you have it written here.  The one on the website sample is encapsulated in a `function` declaration, which would effectively scope it to the lifetime of the page the script is sitting in.  Try the sample.

Comment: As an aside, `if (jQuery('#renewalNotice').length)  {` doesn't demonstrate very good coding style.  Are you checking for length not equal to zero here?

Comment: i mean it was working fine before.